# JS mathematic, live counting

Tags: javascript, math, syntax

I am trying to make live mathematic calculation based on characters count.
Counting of characters works, but other variables like dividing this sum by 1500 or multiplication of this sum by 30, doesn't work. Console tell's me nothing, but in text I am getting "NaN".

I am beginner in mathematics in JS and i don't see why it does not works.
All sources in google tells me that it is good writed.

I am attaching screen of html and code under this text.
On screen is pasted exactly 3000 letters.

Please help <3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojhgq.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function count()
{
  var total=document.getElementById("text").value;
  total=total.replace(/\s/g, '');
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="total: <span>"+total.length+"</span>";

    var divided=total.lenght/1500;
    document.getElementById("divided").innerHTML="divided: <span>"+divided+"</span>";

    var price=divided*30;
    document.getElementById("pricing").innerHTML="price: <span>"+price+"</span>";
}
</script>


    

    <div id="pricing-counter">
<p id="total">total:<span>0</span></p>
<p id="divided">divided:<span>0</span></p>
<p id="pricing">price:<span>0</span></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: where are you calling the function count?, I dont see that code

Comment: NaN means Not a Number. It is an object in JS that you get when you try to add a string to a number for example. You can read about it here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: @Amaarockz can you tell me how?
Tought var x=y/value should do the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo in the line where you set `divided`

```js
function count()
{
  var total=document.getElementById("text").value;
  total=total.replace(/\s/g, '');
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="total: <span>"+total.length+"</span>";

    var divided=total.length/1500; // Typo corrected
    document.getElementById("divided").innerHTML="divided: <span>"+divided+"</span>";

    var price=divided*30;
    document.getElementById("pricing").innerHTML="price: <span>"+price+"</span>";
}
```

```html
 <div id="pricing-counter">
<input id="text"></input>
<button onclick="count()">Count</button>
<p id="total">total:<span>0</span></p>
<p id="divided">divided:<span>0</span></p>
<p id="pricing">price:<span>0</span></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: OMG that was it! Thank you very much! 
Now only i need to convert it into shorter output and everything is great <3

Comment: @TomekPrabucki - Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer